A short "space-opera" with references to ancient Greece's city states vs the Persian Achaemedian Empire
I read this story more than 40 years ago, probably in a collection. Technically it might be a novelette rather than a short story, but no longer than that. Short as it is, it is a space mini-opera.
Mankind has colonised a sizable fraction of the Galaxy. Man-controlled space is organised in many polities of a few stars each, constantly fighting each other, and expanding outwards. Earth's polity is the largest and the strongest, but still only a rather small part of the whole.
Then mankind realised that some other species from a distant original point was also expanding and the spheres of influence met. More and more skirmishes happened on the boundary. Contrary to humans the aliens had a single, huge, polity.
The story has two main characters, say AAA and BBB.
AAA is an idealist. He believes that all mankind must unite to fight the other species, and that people should understand that obvious fact. He is often jailed for his ideas.
BBB is a realist. He know humans do not act rationally. He gets higher and higher in the military and political hierarchy of Earth whose general attitude is to compromise with the aliens, to the displeasure of most other human worlds.
At the end, BBB explains to AAA that all of Earth's strategy, of which he was one of the main proponents, was based on the wars between the city-states of ancient Greece and the Persian Achaemedian Empire. The city-states, constantly warring each other, developed much better weapons and military tactics than the Persians. The danger was to have some city-states on the side of the Persians. But when the Persians attacked, a united front of all Greeks easily defeated the Persian army. Similarly it was important for the human polities to improve their weapons and military tactics by fighting each other. But when the time was right, they were able to fight the aliens and defeat them. Also, the strategy was to avoid the risk of too many human worlds fighting on the side of the aliens (which was indeed the case of some Greek city-states, but not too many), and his strategy for this had worked out, I'm not sure how it happened, but is was based on seeming to compromise with the aliens till the last minute. He offers AAA an important role in politics now that their common aim, unifying all mankind against the aliens has been achieved even though that happened against AAA's principles through BBB's oblique methods.

This is almost definitely "In a Good Cause—" (1951) by Isaac Asimov.  First published in New Tales of Space and Time (ed. Raymond J. Healy), it was later republished as "Ideals Die Hard" in Authentic Science Fiction, March 1957, which you can read at the Internet Archive.  New Tales of Space and Time is also available to borrow from the Internet Archive (free registration required).
The bit about the Greeks and Persia:

"But our very disagreements are our strength! Your Federalist party used to speak of ancient Greece a great deal once. Do you remember? But your people always missed the point. To be sure, Greece could never unite and was, therefore, ultimately conquered. But even in her state of
disunion, she defeated the gigantic Persian Empire. Why?
"I would like to point out that the Greek city-states over centuries had fought with one another. They were forced to specialize in things military to an extent far beyond the Persians. Even the Persians themselves realized that, and in the last century of their imperial existence, Greek mercenaries formed the most valued parts of their armies.
"The same might be said of the small nation-states of preatomic Europe, which in centuries of fighting had advanced their military arts to the point where they could overcome and hold for two hundred years the comparatively gigantic empires of Asia.

The plot summary on Wikipedia notes the differences between the characters:

Altmayer and his friend Geoffrey Stock have opposing positions when conscripted into military service for a war between human-occupied star systems. Stock willingly reports for military duty, whilst Altmayer protests, believing that the various interstellar nations of humanity should be united against the Diaboli, an intelligent non-human race that also occupies several planetary systems in the galaxy.
Over a 45-year period, Stock reaches high military rank and then political office, whilst Altmayer is imprisoned and kept under house arrest several times for his radical idealism. He starts political parties and protest movements, all of which fail to achieve their objectives of uniting humanity.

